# DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet Fill challenge

Tags: c#

I need help to make Excel cell fill work. No error is reported. The Font part uses the last font declared, and the ForeColor and Backcolor properties give me a headache.

**Here are snippets of the code:**

```
private static WorkbookStylesPart Worksheet_Style(SpreadsheetDocument document)
{
    WorkbookStylesPart create_style = document.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
    Stylesheet wbss = new Stylesheet();

    Fonts fonts = new Fonts(); // wbss.GetFirstChild<Fonts>();
    Fills fills = new Fills(); // wbss.GetFirstChild<Fills>();
    CellFormats cfmts = new CellFormats(); //  wbss.GetFirstChild<CellFormats>();
    Borders borders = new Borders(); // wbss.GetFirstChild<Borders>();

    Font fontHeader = new Font(); // Header font
    FontName segoeUiSemibold = new FontName() { Val = "Segoe UI Semibold" };
    FontSize fontSize12 = new FontSize() { Val = 12 };
    fontHeader.Append(segoeUiSemibold);
    fontHeader.Append(fontSize12);

    Font fontText = new Font(); // Text font
    FontName segoeUi = new FontName() { Val = "Segoe UI" };
    FontSize fontSize11 = new FontSize() { Val = 11 };
    fontText.Append(segoeUi);
    fontText.Append(fontSize11);

    // Append both fonts
    fonts.Count = (UInt32Value)2U;
    fonts.Append(fontText);
    fonts.Append(fontHeader);

    //Append fills
    fills.Count = (UInt32Value)2U;
    PatternFill fillSolidBlack = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid };
    ForegroundColor fgWhite = new ForegroundColor() { Rgb = "FFFFFFFF" };
    BackgroundColor bgBlack = new BackgroundColor() { Rgb = "FF000000" };
    fillSolidBlack.Append(fgWhite);
    fillSolidBlack.Append(bgBlack);

    PatternFill fillSolidWhite = new PatternFill() { PatternType = PatternValues.Solid };
    ForegroundColor fgBlack = new ForegroundColor() { Rgb = "FF000000" };
    BackgroundColor bgWhite = new BackgroundColor() { Rgb = "FFFFFFFF" };
    fillSolidWhite.Append(fgBlack);
    fillSolidWhite.Append(bgWhite);

    Fill fillWhite = new Fill();
    fillWhite.Append(fillSolidWhite);
    fills.Append(fillWhite);

    Fill fillBlack = new Fill();
    fillBlack.Append(fillSolidBlack);
    fills.Append(fillBlack);

    // Append borders - a must, in my case just default
    borders.Count = (UInt32Value)1U;
    Border border0 = new Border();     // Default border
    borders.Append(border0);

    // CellFormats
    cfmts.Count = (UInt32Value)2U;
    CellFormat cellFmtHeader = new CellFormat() { FontId = 1, FillId = 1, BorderId = 0 }; // Header style : Mandatory | Style ID =0
    CellFormat cellFmtText = new CellFormat() { FontId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0 }; // Text style
    //CellFormat date_format = new CellFormat() { BorderId = 0, FillId = 0, FontId = 0, NumberFormatId = 14, FormatId = 0, ApplyNumberFormat = true };
    //CellFormat number_format = new CellFormat() { BorderId = 0, FillId = 0, FontId = 0, NumberFormatId = 4, FormatId = 0, ApplyNumberFormat = true }; // format like "#,##0.00"

    cfmts.Append(cellFmtHeader);
    cfmts.Append(cellFmtText);
    //cellformats.Append(date_format);
    //cellformats.Append(number_format);

    // Append everyting to stylesheet  - Preserve the ORDER !
    wbss.Append(fonts);
    wbss.Append(fills);
    wbss.Append(borders);
    wbss.Append(cfmts);

    //Save style for finish
    create_style.Stylesheet = wbss;
    create_style.Stylesheet.Save();

    return create_style;
}

protected void bEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
        "Alarm Task Log.xlsx");
    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filePath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            var sheetData = new SheetData();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

            //Adding styles to worksheet
            WorkbookStylesPart stylesPart = Worksheet_Style(document);

            Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "Tasks" };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            Row headerRow = new Row();
            List<String> cols = new List<string>()
            {
                "Short Name", "Long Name", "Task Date", "Task Start", "Task End"
            };
            foreach (var col in cols)
            {
                Cell c = new Cell
                {
                    DataType = CellValues.String,
                    CellValue = new CellValue(col),
                    StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)0U
                };
                headerRow.AppendChild(c);
            }
            sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

            Row dataRow = new Row();
            List<String> texts = new List<string>()
            {
                tbShortTaskName.Text, tbLongTaskName.Text, dtTaskStart.Value.Date.ToShortDateString(),
                dtTaskStart.Value.ToShortTimeString(), dtTaskEnd.Value.ToShortTimeString()
            };

            foreach (var text in texts)
            {
                Cell c = new Cell
                {
                    DataType = CellValues.String,
                    CellValue = new CellValue(text),
                    StyleIndex = (UInt32Value)1U
                };
                dataRow.AppendChild(c);
            }
            sheetData.AppendChild(dataRow);

            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

**The resulting XML:**

```
<x:styleSheet xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
<x:fills count="2">
<x:fill>
<x:patternFill patternType="solid">
<x:fgColor rgb="FF000000"/>
<x:bgColor rgb="FFFFFFFF"/>
</x:patternFill>
</x:fill>
<x:fill>
<x:patternFill patternType="solid">
<x:fgColor rgb="FFFFFFFF"/>
<x:bgColor rgb="FF000000"/>
</x:patternFill>
</x:fill>
</x:fills>
<x:fonts count="2">
<x:font>
<x:name val="Segoe UI"/>
<x:sz val="11"/>
</x:font>
<x:font>
<x:name val="Segoe UI Semibold"/>
<x:sz val="12"/>
</x:font>
</x:fonts>
<x:borders count="1">
<x:border/>
</x:borders>
<x:cellXfs count="2">
<x:xf fontId="1" fillId="1" borderId="0"/>
<x:xf fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0"/>
</x:cellXfs>
</x:styleSheet>
```

The .xlsx file looks normal, except the last font declared was used for both the header and data rows and no black background/white foreground is shown.
Any help would be sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Find where Microsoft has hidden the _OpenXML Productivity Tool_ (ah, here: https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5).  Now create before and after versions of your file (before you do the operation and after) using Excel.  Save them.  Use the Tool to compare the two files.  You will see all the stuff you need to do to make it work.  The tool can also decompile an Excel file into OpenXML source (C# or XML) and tell you why an invalid file is invalid.  **Very Handy**

Comment: Thanks, FlyDog! There is no "before file", as the code creates the .xlsx

Comment: Also, I have OpenXML SDK v.2.20 installed. The tool wants me to regress to v.2.15 and even then it will not install...

Comment: That's a shame.  That tool is magically useful.  What I was suggesting was a) comment out the part that you can't get working and run your tool (saving the output file).  b) Open that saved file in Excel and save it again (Excel will add a bunch of goop you don't care about, but it makes sense here).  c) Then copy the file and open the copy.  d) manually do what you want to do within Excel and save it.  Now you have two files, one that's mostly unchanged, and the other whose only difference is the stuff you haven't figured out.  Diff the files in the tool and you should see a path forward

Comment: Thanks, FlyDog, that was very helpful. I found the solution.